# Loggin en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero que en mi aplicación un usuario no pueda hacer loggin hasta que el administrador de la página no active a este usuario, a través de una función que he creado que cambie un campo del modelo User 'active' a true en la base de datos.
He modificado la función login de LoginController tal que:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
        $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

     if ($this->guard()->validate($this->credentials($request))) {
       $user = $this->guard()->getLastAttempted();

        if($user->active && $this->attemptLogin($request)){
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }
    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Donde pensaba que :

```
     if ($this->guard()->validate($this->credentials($request))) {
       $user = $this->guard()->getLastAttempted();

        if($user->active && $this->attemptLogin($request)){
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }
```

Me permitía no loggear al usuario hasta que el campo active estuviera a true, pero no funciona.

Alguna ayudita???

Comment: Yo usuaría un [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) para esa ruta login y permitiría acceder a solo los que tengan status activo.

Comment: Fijate que puedes [Especificar condiciones adicionales](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#specifying-additional-conditions) cuando haces una autenticación manual de usuarios

Answer (score 2):

La solución más óptima a tu problema y que te permitirá una mayor flexibilidad a futuro es crear un Middleware. Un ejemplo de implementación sería:

Crear el middleware (`$ php artisan make:middleware Active`)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Active
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->active) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Luego, registras el middleware en `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
   ...
   ...
  
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'active' => \App\Http\Middleware\Active::class,
        ...
        ...
   ];
}
```

Y haces uso del middleware sobre aquellas rutas que corresponda:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/* Private */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'active']], function () {

    // Rutas para usuarios autenticados y activos
    ...
    ...
    ...
});
```